# Puma fails to start on jRuby with error: The signal USR1 is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, jruby, jrubyonrails, puma

I am trying to deploy a simple rails app on my VPS, but I always get this error message, when capistrano tries to start puma:

```
The signal USR1 is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
* Listening on unix:///home/user/apps/myapp/current/tmp/sockets/myapp.socket
NativeLibrary.java:87:in `loadNativeLibraries': java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /lib/libc.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
    from NativeLibrary.java:70:in `getNativeLibraries'
    from NativeLibrary.java:49:in `getSymbolAddress'
    from NativeLibrary.java:59:in `findSymbolAddress'
    from AsmLibraryLoader.java:117:in `generateInterfaceImpl'
    from AsmLibraryLoader.java:59:in `loadLibrary'
    from NativeLibraryLoader.java:43:in `loadLibrary'
    from LibraryLoader.java:228:in `load'
    from Library.java:123:in `loadLibrary'
    from Library.java:80:in `loadLibrary'
    from Native.java:40:in `<clinit>'
    from Native.java:60:in `libsocket'
    from Native.java:68:in `socket'
    from UnixServerSocketChannel.java:38:in `<init>'
    from UnixServerSocket.java:29:in `<init>'
    from UnixServerSocketChannel.java:48:in `open'
    from RubyUNIXSocket.java:243:in `init_unixsock'
    from RubyUNIXServer.java:69:in `initialize'
    from RubyUNIXServer$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.gen:-1:in `call'
    from JavaMethod.java:971:in `call'
    from JavaMethod.java:677:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:286:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:81:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:85:in `call'
    from RubyClass.java:825:in `newInstance'
    from RubyIO.java:852:in `newInstance'
    from RubyIO$INVOKER$s$0$0$newInstance.gen:-1:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:210:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:206:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
    from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from EnsureNode.java:96:in `interpret'
    from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:225:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:214:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:346:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:204:in `call'
    from FCallTwoArgNode.java:38:in `interpret'
    from DAsgnNode.java:110:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:118:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from WhenOneArgNode.java:36:in `whenSlowTest'
    from WhenOneArgNode.java:46:in `when'
    from CaseNode.java:133:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:112:in `INTERPRET_BLOCK'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:206:in `evalBlockBody'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:157:in `yield'
    from Block.java:142:in `yield'
    from RubyArray.java:1606:in `eachCommon'
    from RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    from RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen:-1:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:316:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:145:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:154:in `callIter'
    from CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:225:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:214:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:346:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:204:in `call'
    from CallTwoArgNode.java:59:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:182:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from VCallNode.java:88:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:116:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:116:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:182:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from CallNoArgNode.java:60:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:182:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from CallNoArgNode.java:60:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from RootNode.java:129:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:121:in `INTERPRET_ROOT'
    from Ruby.java:838:in `runInterpreter'
    from Ruby.java:2766:in `loadFile'
    from ExternalScript.java:66:in `load'
    from LoadService.java:359:in `load'
    from RubyKernel.java:1109:in `loadCommon'
    from RubyKernel.java:1101:in `load19'
    from RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load19.gen:-1:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:210:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:206:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from bin/puma:16:in `__file__'
    from bin/puma:-1:in `load'
    from Ruby.java:811:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:804:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:673:in `runNormally'
    from Ruby.java:522:in `runFromMain'
    from Main.java:395:in `doRunFromMain'
    from Main.java:290:in `internalRun'
    from Main.java:217:in `run'
    from Main.java:197:in `main'
! Error starting new process as daemon, exitting
```

My VPS runs Centos 6 and jRuby 1.7.11.
I also tried to run bundle install --binstubs then

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/puma -p 9292 -e production -C config/puma.rb
```

But still the same error occurs.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

The "USR1" text isn't an error, it's just a warning when running under JRuby.

The real error is this one:

```
NativeLibrary.java:87:in `loadNativeLibraries':
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /lib/libc.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

This is caused because you are running a 64-bit JRE, but trying to load a 32-bit libc.

Comment: Hi Shepmaster! Thanks for the help. Figured it out in the meantime. Reinstalled a 32 bit version of Centos 6 on my VPS and now it works. Still don't know how this could happen on the 64 bit though. Will try it again soon.

Comment: The problem is happening for me due to puma needing to use unix sockets. This drops down to the NativeLibrary apparently.

You can test ruby / jruby against this: 

ruby -e "puts Java::jnr.unixsocket.Native.libsocket"